# GSON - JsonElement to JsonObject conversion error

Tags: java, json, gson

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
JsonReader reader = new JsonReader(new InputStreamReader(
            new URL("http://api.mineplex.com/pc/player/abc?apiKey=1")
              .openConnection().getInputStream()));
JsonElement json1 = gson.fromJson(reader, JsonElement.class);
JsonObject jsonObject1 = json1.getAsJsonObject();
```

This class crashes with this:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not a JSON Object: "<html>"
    at com.google.gson.JsonElement.getAsJsonObject(JsonElement.java:90) ~[gson-2.2.4.jar:?]
```

Why?

Comment: I'm guessing, but try changing "http" with "https".

Comment: @Tobb https gives certificate error.

Comment: @MCCCS the link you are using is redirecting to the actual page, eventhough browsers are fogiving enough to do the redirect from http to https Java does not do that for you, u may consider using https instead of http protocol

Comment: @nafas Could you please post this as an answer? You're right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the link you are using is `redirecting` to the actual page which is redirecting from `HTTP` to `HTTPS` protocol,

The issue is caused by the HTTP/HTTPS redirection policy implemented in Sun JRE

Even though, browsers are forgiving enough to do this redirect, Java does not do that for you for security reason, In your case you can just simply use `HTTPS` protocol to remove any redirection.

Answer (score 1):

Seems you are reading a HTML content webpage not a JSON resource

Check what this URL returns:

http://api.mineplex.com/pc/player/abc?apiKey=1

And verify the content type should be JSON

Answer (score 1):

This is what your call is returning:

```
<html>
   <head></head>
   <body>
      <pre style="word-wrap: break-word; white-space: pre-wrap;">{"statusCode":401,"error":"Unauthorized","message":"Invalid API Key. To get an api key use the /api command in game"}</pre>
   </body>
</html>
```

Besides this page contains an JSON, its not one. You shoulde look for the API document to return directly a json, or manipulate this HTML in Java and get only the JSON part